# How to install PhpUnit with XAMPP using composer?

Tags: windows, xampp, phpunit, composer-php

Im trying to install PHPUnit on Xampp using Composer.I have followed the steps from the following link
http://woeiyu.com/software/php/installing-phpunit/
but im got the error "proc_open(NUL): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" while executing composer update

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you skip XAMPP and use Git. Much easier. But you actually don't need those two to install it.

Put this in your `composer.json`

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.0.*"
    }
}
```

Run it like this in Git or XAMPP `composer update` after that `composer install`
and that's it. You successfully downloaded and installed PHPUnit. It's located in your root vendor/

Answer (score 1):

You can install `phpunit` with `composer` globally using

```
$ composer global require phpunit/phpunit
```

For reference see https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global.